# .NET MS Word Interop - How to write data to tables quickly

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I have a Word document that is used as a template (but is not a Word template, just a .doc file) with tables in them that I need to populate with data. I am not having trouble populating the tables with data or writing anything that I need. The problem I am having is that it is taking forever to write the data because Word appears to be typing the text out in real-time.

The only possible solution I have seen online is to set.Visible = False, but I am doing that and it takes about 10 minutes to write 1000 rows of data.

I am upgrading a report application that was able to do the same thing in 5 seconds but it was written in VB6, so I can't imagine that it can't go just as fast in .NET.

Here's the setup for the code example below:
I have the data in a .NET DataTable with a bookmark name and a value. Multiple occurrences of the bookmark name identify which table these should go into. All of that is irrelevant because it all works, unless I am doing it in a way that causes .TypeText() to go really slow. I even did some debugging and just the .TypeText() appears to take 1 whole second each time, which makes 1000 rows take anywhere from 10-15 minutes to write out.

```
    Dim WordApp As New Word.Application()
    WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Report_Template.doc", [ReadOnly]:=True)

    With WordApp
        Try
            .Visible = False

            .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2("C:\Report.doc")
            .ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = False

            With .Selection
                Dim Bookmark As String

                For Each BookmarkRow As DataRow In MyDataTable

                    Bookmark = BookmarkRow("Bookmark")

                    'create a sub datatable of each distinct bookmark name
                    Dim BookmarkView As New DataView(dtItemizedValues)
                    BookmarkView.RowFilter = "BOOKMARK = '" & Bookmark & "'"
                    Dim BookmarkData As DataTable = BookmarkView.ToTable()

                    'go to the bookmark
                    .GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark, , , Bookmark)

                    'move to the table for this section
                    .GoTo(Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToTable, Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToNext)

                    'loop through rows
                    For Each Row As DataRow In BookmarkData.Rows
                        If .Text.Length > 0 Then
                            .SelectCell()
                            .Cut()
                        End If

                        .TypeText(Text:=Row("Value"))

                        'move to next row
                        .Move(Word.WdUnits.wdRow)
                    Next 'row
                Next 'bookmark


            End With 'with .selection

            .ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
        Catch ex As Exception
            .ActiveDocument.Close()
        Finally
            WordApp.Quit(False)
        End Try
    End With 'with .wordapp
```

Comment: If `TypeText` is slow, could you do it another way?  Perhaps `.Text = Row("Value")`?

Comment: "... appears to be typing the text out in real-time." -That is because that is exactly what that code is telling it to do. The code looks like it was _recorded_ and then modified to perform a loop. That is not going to perform very well as it is just simulating the UI interaction. Take some time to learn the [Word Object Model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/word-object-model-overview) and write your automation code to manipulate the data directly and not via simulated user actions.  Hint: `BookMark` has a `Range` Property that in turn has a `Text` Property that can be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa537149%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about this, many years ago... Constructing a table, cell-by-cell or row-by-row and filling it with data is *slow*. And the longer the table gets, the slower things become due to how Word repaginates.

The essential steps for achieving top efficiency are:

- concatenate all the data in a character-delimited string
- assign that string to a `Range` object in Word
- use `ConvertToTable` to turn the string into a table

Simple sample:

```
//Insert table at end of currently active document
Sub ConvertTextStringToTable()
    Dim doc As Word.Document = Word.Application.ActiveDocument
    Dim rng As Word.Range = doc.Content
    Dim data As String
    data = "one" & vbTab & "two" & vbTab & "three" & vbCr & _
           "1" & vbTab & "2" & vbTab & "3" & vbCr

    rng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
    rng.Text = data
    Dim tbl as Word.Table = rng.ConvertToTable(vbTab)
End Sub
```